# I am making a todo list program where i can add my works

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a To-Do list in python.I want to add new tasks in my dictionary and want them to appear when i call them.How can I do that?

```
dictionary = {}  # creating a empty dictionary
while True:  # to run the program infinite times
    qs = input('->').lower()  # command?
    if "todo" in qs:  # check the command
            p = dictionary
            print(p)
    elif "add" in qs:  # command
        i = input("what to add?")  # what to add in the todo list
        dictionary = i
        print("Added " + i + " to your To Do list")
    else:
        print("There was a error!")
```

The code I tried worked but not as I expected.
It only gave one todo work though I wanted to get all the works I added to the dictionary.
So, what can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reassigning the dictionary to an individual item:

```
dictionary = i
```

You want to add to the dictionary, presumably like this:

```
n += 1
dictionary[n] = i
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're *overwriting* the dictionary rather than adding a new key/value.

Change

```
dictionary = i
```

To

```
index += 1
dictionary[index] = i
```

and this should work. You could also use `update()`, or even a list `[]`

Answer (score 0):

The way you seem to want to use it, you are probably better of using a `list`

Replace `dictionary = {}` with `dictionary = []` and then replace `dictionary = i` with `dictionary.append(i)`